# If string does NOT contain value

Tags: javascript

I have

```
if (windowURL.indexOf('example.com/blog/') > -1)
```

but how do I code if it does NOT contain that string? Is it simply:

```
if (!windowURL.indexOf('example.com/blog/') > -1)
```

or is there a better way? I see other examples that use `===` but no examples specific to my particular syntax. Thank you.

Comment: Mathematically `!(x > -1)` === `x <= 1`. Since "not found" always returns `-1` you could just do `x === -1`

Comment: OK, thanks! So it really is just a matter of switching the `>` to `===`'.

Comment: Yes. `indexOf` simply returns `-1` if it doesn't find anything, hence you can safely check for that value. You can also use `string1.includes(string2) === false`

Comment: Mathematically `<=` is the inverse of `>`